# JButton only appears after hovered over, while using CardLayout for handeling scenes

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I am trying to create a simple game in Java, but I got stuck on creating a system for handeling the different scenes and the trasitioning between them.

These are my classes:

The scene manager that controls what scene is currently shown by using the cardLayout.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SceneManager extends JFrame{
    private static SceneManager single_instance = null;

    public final CardLayout cardLayout;
    private final Scene mainMenuScene;
    private final Scene gameScene;

    private SceneManager() {
        super("My Game");
        setSize(new Dimension(1000,350));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        this.setLayout(cardLayout);

        mainMenuScene = new MainMenuScene(this);
        mainMenuScene.setName("mainMenuScene");
        this.add(mainMenuScene, "mainMenuScene");

        gameScene = new GameScene(this);
        gameScene.setName("gameScene");
        this.add(gameScene, "gameScene");

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static synchronized SceneManager getInstance()
    {
        if (single_instance == null)
            single_instance = new SceneManager();

        return single_instance;
    }

    public void switchToMainMenu() {
        cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "mainMenuScene");
    }

    public void switchToGame() {
        cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "gameScene");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SceneManager sc = SceneManager.getInstance();
    }
}
```

The Scene parent class serving as a template for all the scenes. It uses a thread game loop system, because i want to have animations even the seemingly static scenes, such as the main menu. However, i dont know if im doing this the right way as it is my first time working with threads and with java in general.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public abstract class Scene extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private boolean isPaused = true;
    private int FPS;
    protected SceneManager sceneManager;

    private Thread thread;

    public Scene(SceneManager sceneManager){
        this.FPS = 30;

        this.sceneManager = sceneManager;

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 350));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent evt) {
                pause();
            }
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent evt) {
                resume();
            }
        });

        startThread();
    }

    public void startThread(){
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        this.isPaused = true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        this.isPaused = false;
    }

    public boolean isPaused(){
        return isPaused;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1_000_000_000. / FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;

        while (thread != null){
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;

            if (delta >= 1) {
                // Only update and repaint if the game is not paused
                if(!isPaused) {
                    repaint();
                    update();
                }
                delta --;
            }
            if(timer >= 1_000_000_000){
                timer = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void update();

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

        draw(g2d);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

And then there are the two scenes:

Main menu:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainMenuScene extends Scene {
    private JButton button;

    public MainMenuScene(SceneManager sceneManager) {
        super(sceneManager);
        button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(this::onButtonClick);
        button.setLocation(100,100);
        button.setSize(200,100);
        this.add(button, "button1");
        this.validate();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }

    public void update() {}

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {}

    private void onButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        sceneManager.switchToGame();
    }
}
```

And the game scene:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GameScene extends Scene {

    private int x;

    JButton button;

    public GameScene(SceneManager sceneManager) {
        super(sceneManager);
        button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(this::onButtonClick);
        button.setLocation(100,100);
        button.setSize(200,100);
        this.add(button, "button1");
        this.validate();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }

    public void update(){
        x += 2;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.fillRect(x,50,200,200);
    }


    private void onButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        sceneManager.switchToMainMenu();
    }
}
```

The problem i'm experiencing is that when i launch the program, the button is invisible until i hover over it. Then, if i call resume(), the button flickers when hovered over (it becomes visible the moment i touch it and then the next 'frame' it becomes invisible again until i move my mouse again). I have no idea what is causing this behavior, so any help would be much appreciated.

P.S.: One thing i discovered is that when i set the layout of the mainMenu to the cardLayout of the SceneManager (I call this.setLayout(sceneManager.cardLayout); in the MainMenu constructor), the button shows straight up form the beggining, but it covers the whole window, instead of being of the specified size.

P.P.S: I also tried putting revalidate() in all sorts of places in the code (the update() method, the menu constructor, both...), but with no success. It might be because im not really sure what it does, so i might have benn using it incorrectly the whole time.

Comment: *I also tried putting revalidate()* - validate() or revalidate() are not needed. Those methods are only used if you add components to a visible frame. *...but it covers the whole window...* - because the panel uses a BorderLayout. The default constraint is the CENTER which will resize the button to fill the entire space. The default layout manager of a panel is a FlowLayout. Leave it like that. Note a layout manger should be set BEFORE you add components to the panel. Setting the size/location should NOT be used. It is the job of the layout manager to set these properties.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to better understand how to use layout managers.

Comment: Also, maybe your Thread needs to "sleep" for a period of time to allow the frame to repaint itself.

Comment: in addition to the comments by @camickr - you __must not__ dispose the graphics that's passed into paintComponent, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911743/why-does-calling-dispose-on-graphics-object-cause-jpanel-to-not-render-any-com

Comment: Ok it was the dispose that caused the error, thanks @kleopatra

Answer (score 0):

The problems were caused by calling g2d.dispose() in the PaintComponent() method of the Scene class. This mistake was found by kleopatra in the comments.